# Shrinking of jDataTable (Jquery-DataTable) when its load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am binding the GridView in Server side then I am converting  as J-Table in client side using the following Js function.

Initially  J-Table is **shrinking** in size then it load normally. This gives very ugly look in t application...

I know its happening cos of the time delay where to convert grid into Jquery-Tables . But how to avoid that shrinking....

I tried Setting width as 100% in fnDrawCallback, preDrawCallBack and all.. But its not worked..

This is the code I used to convert as J-DataTable .. I am Calling this after bind the grid in server side..

```
function displayPqaAnalysis() {     
    var grvPqaAnalysisTable = document.getElementById("<%=grvPqaAnalysis.ClientID%>");
    if (grvPqaAnalysisTable != null) {
        var oTable = $('#' + '<%=grvPqaAnalysis.ClientID%>').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            'iDisplayLength': pageSize,
            "bPagination": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "width": "100%",                    
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ bSortable: false, aTargets: [0]}]   
        });
    }
}
```

The Concept is First I bind t Gridview in server side then converting it into J-DataTable using t above Javascript function.

I hope U can understand Myquestion. Please revert me back ur suggestions

Thanks,
Sarath